# Microphone sound into game propagation

Tags: sound, sound-effects

Had been any efforts made
to stream real-time sound from the microphone (user's voice)
into the game currently played?

This way you could hear echo of your own voice
when you walked into enclosed space,
strong or faint voices in a multiplayer game depending
on distances between players, ...

Comment: I don't know, but one potential problem with this would be latency, as it's very noticeable when you have even just a 10ms delay between making a noise and hearing it. Lower latency is possible but it can require more CPU time.

Comment: some games use the microphone to issue orders, I think Tom Clancy: End War did it, not too sure if there are any games that use DSP's to affect the sounds you make, unless you look at stuff like Singstar and Lips. interesting concept though, could make for a very nice feature in an atmospheric horror title!

Comment: The latency, as @Kylotan notes, is really bad on the ears.  Even pro audio recording gear uses hard-wired monitoring connections instead of passing the microphone input through all the electronics because just a little latency throws a singer off the beat.  It's not that no one has tried, it's that it inherently sucks.

Answer (score 1):

[Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) supports positional audio by means of plugins for various games. So you'll hear other players speaking seemingly from the relative position their avatars inside the game are to you.

But yeah, it's not exactly what you are talking about. I love your idea btw., I hope someone uses that concept in a novel way.